# Does Fortification also ignore special effects?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, critical-hit

Creatures and foes with higher level and CR offers additional effects on critical hits. Like:

> **Attacks:** Slam 31d6+5/19-20 (x2 + Disease on critical hit)

A player with heavy fortification will ignore the x2 part and will take normal damage.

Does (any kind of) fortification also ignore supernatural or spell-like effects like disease in this scenario?

Comment: What creature has that example ability?

Comment: @HeyICanChan from Epic Level Handbook Pg: 224 Uvuudaum, Wisdom Drain.  Description explains as `That effect permanenetly reduces a living Opponent's wisdom by 2d4 when the creature hits with its head spike,or twice that amount on a critical hit.`

This book is 3e, not 3.5, but erreta do not include any fix for that description so we cana ssume it is also valid for 3.5ed

Maybe there could be other similar effects for other creatures somewhere in the MM's or other books that contains monster descriptions.

Answer (score 8):

> #### Fortification
>
> This suit of armor or shield produces a magical force that protects vital areas of the wearer more effectively. When a critical hit or sneak attack is scored on the wearer, there is a chance that **the critical hit or sneak attack is negated** and damage is instead rolled normally.

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

The critical hit is negated; one effect of that, explicitly listed, is that damage is rolled normally, but any *other* effects of the critical hit are also negated, because the critical hit itself is negated and it is as if it never happened.

Comment: Yup, but for ease of reading, I'd bold the "damage is instead rolled normally" just so theres no confusion

Comment: @Ben-Jamin I disagree: the bit about normal damage was already noted in the question, and the question is primarily about *non-damage* effects tacked on to a critical hit. The important information here is that the critical hit itself is negated. *Fortification* could easily have been written to use normal damage, but otherwise have the hit still count as critical and therefore have other effects apply. I emphasize the part that indicates that, though that is a conceivable effect in the game, it’s not the one *fortification* was written with.

Comment: A point of note: I seem to remember some FAQ or Sage Advice that disagrees with that.

Comment: @martixy Even if you were to link to that, I wouldn’t care because [the D&D 3.5e FAQ is often wrong and never worth paying much mind to](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60044/4563).